# Fitting a piece of steet around a corner / path

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier

I have a bit of a problem here.

I've got a piece of street (Here called Street_Raw) that I want to fit along a path (NurbsCurve).
Now, I've watched some tutorials on how to do it, though it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to.

My piece of street somehow starts in the in some for me undefined location and also falls short to compleat the path. (See screen attached)

[image: General Image of the Problem]

In the Image you can also see from where to where I want my curve.
(Eg. from the bottom of the plane center to the right center of the plane (0, -12.5, 0) over (0,0,0) to (12.5,0,0))

Now, I've tried to help myself already and asked the all mighty ChatGPT which gave me the following:
https://chat.openai.com/share/c019b32e-6fa2-4b16-8f25-38d0bce08bf5

Overall... it didn't help.

Adding insult to injury, the right bottom part of the curve, as seen in the screen, looks additionally weard and mangled together.

I am a relative noob when it comes to blender, so... if you have advice I would greatly weclome it.

Making things harder... both the defined start and end point I've defined are there, cause I need this piece to be exact, as I am trying to build a set (streight, curve, ...........) which need to all fit together to be used in a Unity application for some rudimentary road generation.

Here are additional pictures to maybe help:
[image]
[image]

If you understand my problem and are able to help, I would be very greatful!
If not, thank you anyway for your time!
Have a nice day!

Ps.: I've decided to add a share link to the file from my onedrive. I hope it helps.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvUz5L-rsXt2j_REAHRWyKPukK-naA?e=VUEjej

Comment: See if [this](https://youtu.be/lRK8UMudejg) tutorial from Ryan King will help get you started.